# In-app purchases for client , payment problems

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment, iphone-developer-program

I am building an application for a client with In-app-purchases. I am wondering if the client needs to create with own developers account so that he can be paid from Apple. Or is it something it can be arranged through our Apple developers program.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your client must create a developer account for him and eventually add you as a member of its team by deciding which role you will have.